# Detect Last click/touch inside the cross-origin iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am looking for solution of the problem – how to detect **last** click/touch inside the cross-origin `iframe`.
(after one visitor end working and leave, site is to reset itself for the next visitor)

I found few similar questions here (some quite complicated, with different aspects), but still didn't really understood answers.

The common code usually looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="400" height="200" src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>

<div id="mesg">---</div> <!-- just for click test-detecting purpose. -->

<script>
    window.onblur = function(){
        mesg.innerHTML += ' Click Detected '; // just for click test-detecting purpose.
        // some clever code here (or elsewhere) to force focus back to main window (to detect next onblur event)
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It perfectly detects first click (visitor starts paging inside the `iframe`).

But how to get focus back to the main window after each click, to detect next `onblur event`?
We tried – `window.focus()`; `top.focus()`; `parent.focus()`; `referrer.focus()` – nothing works of these.

Styling `iframe` as `{pointer-events:none;}` – disables possibility to interact with elements in it.

Are there solution at all?

Would be much, Much Thankful for any help.